# If $ f $ is injective and $ g $ is injective, then $ f \circ g $ is surjective.

Tags: proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition

I can prove that if $ f $ and $ g $ are both injective, then $ f \circ g $ is injective, but I don’t know how to prove that $ f \circ g $ is surjective.

Comment: Good thing you can't prove it: it's false.

Comment: so how would i provide a counter example

Comment: You cannot prove it, because it isn't true. Let $g:(0,1)\to (0,2)$ and $ f:(0,2)\to (0,3)$ both $f(x) =g(x)= x$. $f\circ g$ isn't surjective.

Comment: Choose $g$ to be the identity function and then pick $f$ to be any injective function that is not surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \{a\}$, let $B = \{b\}$, and let $C=\{c_1,c_2\}$.

Define $f:B\to C$ to be $f(b)=c_1$

Define $g:A\to B$ to be $f(a)=b$

Here we have $A\xrightarrow{g} B\xrightarrow{f} C$, $f$ and $g$ are both injective (why?)

But, there is no preimage to $c_2$ (neither in $f$ nor in $f\circ g$).  What does that mean about surjectivity?

---

[image: injectivity surjectivity]

Here is a diagram of what is going on.

Remember the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity:

> A function, $f:X\to Y$ is **injective** (also called **one-to-one**) iff whenever $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ it implies that $x_1=x_2$.

In terms of the picture, a function is injective whenever *there is no element with two (or more) arrows pointing to it*.  You see above that each element has only one or no arrows pointing to it, so both functions are injective.

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is **surjective** (also called **onto**) iff every $y\in Y$ has some $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.  I.e. every element in the codomain has a preimage.  I.e. the Range of $f$ is the same as the Codomain of $f$.

In terms of the picture, a function is surjective whenever *all elements in the codomain have at least one arrow pointing to them*.  Here we see that $2$ does not have an arrow pointing to it, so it is not surjective.

Finish by noting what $f\circ g$ looks like and that $2$ still doesn't have a preimage.

Comment: I was given that if I am to provide a counterexample to let X and Y be subsets of [1,2,3] but I don't understand how to go about doing that

Comment: So, instead of $A=\{a\}$, let it instead be $\{1\}$., instead of $B=\{b\}$ let it instead be $\{1\}$, and instead of $C=\{c_1,c_2\}$, let it instead be $\{1,2\}$.  "*A rose by any other name would smell as sweet*."  A label for a mathematical object is just a label.  You have then the same argument.  $f(1)=1, g(1)=1, f(g(1))=(f\circ g)(1)=1$ but there isn't a preimage for $2$.

Comment: okay so I know that f and g are both injective because it is given the statement but how do I show they are not surjective. Just becuase injectivity does not involve the c2?

Comment: @Zach added more information and a graphical explanation as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, let $f(n)=n+1$, $g(n)=n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. (Where $f,g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.)

Answer (score 0):

To give a counterexample where neither of the injective functions is surjective:

Consider $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, n\mapsto 2n$ and $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, n\mapsto 3n$. Then you get $f\circ g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N, n\mapsto 6n$ which clearly isn't surjective; for example, there's no $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $6n=1$.